# Alert box after redirect

Tags: javascript, html

so i know this may sound stupid, but I want to know if there is any way that i could redirect someone to a website, and then display an alert box on the web page, using either javascript or any other interface that can be weaved into HTML5. I asked some of my classmates, and they didn't know, so I just need a confirmation that this isn't possible.

I have ran a few trials  i found, but on further review, they wouldn't work.

*edit* I have control over the site, but I wish for the box to only pop up if i redirect it.
I can give the code if it would help, but I'm doubtful it will help

sorry for wasting your time if i did.                                        thanks.

Comment: You have no control over the page once it leaves.

Comment: Do you control the other page? Or is it just some third-party site?

Comment: I have edited the post to include details.

Comment: If yu have control than you have options. Just requires code on every page.

Comment: Please show us what you already tried to do so we can see where we can start from

Comment: It's considered best practice on this website to provide the code you are working with so possible answerers don't have to guess what the problem is.

Comment: And actually, not just "some code" but an "MRE" https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: this is currently what I was working with, and saw no way I could modify it. sorry.<html>
<head>
<script>alert("la la la, singing in the shower.");
</script>
<script>
 location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")</script>
</head>
<body>


<p>if you are not redirected</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click here to continue</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
}
</script>


</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Gerard's answer, but using [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). A possibly more standard solution.

On the first page:

```
<script>
  window.location = 'https://{your website here}/?showAlert=true';
</script>
```

Then on the 2nd page.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const showAlert = urlParams.get('showAlert');
if(showAlert === "true") {
   alert("Hello");
}
```

Note this [will not work](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams) in internet explorer

Comment: This is a better approach than the one I posted. I was going for brevity, as the whole premise of this question sounds a little nefarious. Maybe others can suggest some edits to the question to make it more helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

You could communicate to the new site that it's a redirect by appending the route:

On the site you want to redirect from:

```
<script>
  // if you can't use a normal link, change the url with JS
  window.location = 'https://{your website here}/#redirect';
</script>
```

On the site you want to show the alert:

```
<script>
  if (window.location.pathname.includes('#redirect') alert('What you want to say');
</script>
```

If you only have control over the first site, you could `alert` before redirecting, there wouldn't be much difference to the user since the `alert` blocks execution of other code.

Comment: are you missing a paren after `window.location.pathname.includes('#redirect')`

Answer (score 0):

You can call an alert box in a HTML document with JavaScript like this:

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        alert("Hello World!");
    }
```

-> https://jsfiddle.net/u8x6s31v/

You can also redirect somebody, if the page he's visiting is yours. Is that what you mean?

#### Update:

I think you can't see the URL where someone comes from with JavaScript. The only way to trigger scripts for some people is to add a hash.

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        hashUrl = window.location.hash;
          if (hashUrl == "#alert") {
            alert("Hello World!");
          }
    }
```

Then call for example: domain.tld/path/index.html#alert

-> https://jsfiddle.net/u8x6s31v/1/

Comment: currently I already have those scripts, i wanted to trigger an alert box  if  someone was redirected from one of my pages to another

Comment: I updated the answer. The only way is an hash, i think. Or cookies..

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague questions with a lot of possible answers but seeing as how you're new, I'm going to speculate on what you might be asking and try to answer it.

It's not clear what you mean by "redirect".

Is this a server-side redirect like when you move/change a URL and you redirect the old URL to a new URL? Is this a Javascript meta refresh that you put in a 404 template? Is this a redirect that occurs after a user takes an action?

Regardless, you're going to have to "annotate" that user and then take action upon that annotation. The most obvious method would be based on the "referrer" HTTP header but it is also possible to do it based on the presence of a cookie.

Additionally, adding URL parameters to a redirect is trivially easy and often used for stuff like this.

The immediate things that come to my mind would be via Google Analytics (preferably implemented via Google Tag Manager because it'll make it easier).

Look into "outbound link tracking", "cross-domain tracking" and "UTM campaign tracking" (all related to Google Analytics and/or Google Tag Manager) and you'll probably find something that suits your needs.

URL shorteners are commonly used to mask parameters in links and there are open source libraries that allow you to host your own URL shortener (which you could integrate into your redirects) or do some other type of link tracking like is often used for affiliates.